# Declare a variable

Tags: variables, prolog

I didn't touch Prolog since high-school, and even though I've tried to find the info, it didn't help. Below is the example that has to illustrate my problem:

```
%% everybody():- [dana, cody, bess, abby].
%% Everybody = [dana, cody, bess, abby].

likes(dana, cody).
hates(bess, dana).
hates(cody, abby).

hates(X, Y):- \+ likes(X, Y).

likes_somebody(_, []):- fail.
likes_somebody(X, [girl | others]):-
    likes(X, girl) ; likes_somebody(X, others).

likes_everybody(_, []):- true.
likes_everybody(X, [girl | others]):-
    likes(X, girl) , likes_everybody(X, others).

maplist(likes_somebody, [dana, cody, bess, abby], [dana, cody, bess, abby]).
```

How do I declare `everybody` to just be the list of girls? The commented lines are those which I've tried, but I've got bizarre error messages back.

This is the [tutorial](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/prolog/prolog-tutorial.html) I followed more or less so far. I'm using GProlog, if it makes any difference. Sorry for such a basic question. GProlog's manual doesn't deal with language syntax, but I've certainly looked there. As an aside, I would be grateful for information on where to look for language documentation (as opposed to implementation documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every variable in Prolog must begin with an uppercase letter. So for starters, you want `Everybody`, not `everybody`.

Second problem, variables in Prolog are not [assignables](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/words-matter/). So probably what you want to do is make a fact and use that instead:

```
everybody([dana, cody, bess, abby]).
```

Your bottom line of code is actually a fact definition and will attempt to overwrite `maplist/3`. What you probably want to do is put everything above that line into a file (say, called `likes.pl`) and then consult it (`[likes].`). Then you can run a query like this:

```
?- everybody(Everybody), maplist(likes_somebody, Everybody, Everybody).
```

This won't work, because `likes_somebody/2` processes a list in the second argument. The predicate you have for `likes_somebody/2` could be written:

```
likes_somebody(_, []).
```

but still won't mean much. It simply unifies anything with the empty list:

```
?- likes_somebody(chicken_tacos, []).
true.
```

You really need a predicate to tell you if someone is a girl, like this:

```
girl(dana).
girl(cody).
girl(bess).
girl(abby).
```

Then you could do what I think you're trying to do, which is something closer to this:

```
likes_somebody(X) :- girl(X).
```

Then the maplist construction would work like this:

```
everybody(Everybody), maplist(likes_somebody, Everybody).
```

Which would simply return true. You could simplify and eliminate `everybody/1` by instead using `findall(Girl, girl(X), Everybody)` but it's getting weird.

You're trying to do list processing with `likes_everybody/2`, but it's broken because `girl` is literally `girl`, not a variable, and `others` is literally `others`, not a list of some kind that could be the tail of another list.

I think you still have some old ideas you need to cleanse. Read some more, write some more, and your code will start to make a lot more sense.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had to put `?-` before the `maplist`, and yeah, my closest acquittance with Prolog is through Erlang, so I know the syntactic rules about variable names. The predicate as you made it wasn't really what I was trying to do, but thanks for the effort :) You used `finall` - how do you know the names of existing functions? I couldn't find any info about that...

Comment: Because `girl` appeared a lot in your predicates, but not your database, I assumed you were trying to use it as a variable (and `others` can't really work in that position without being a variable). Besides that, your question is how to make `everybody` a variable, not `Everybody`. [The SWI documentation is great for built-ins](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=builtin)--and I strongly recommend that implementation.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I had to fix that. Well, I guess case closed, although it still looks ugly as my entire life :(

Comment: Prolog's aesthetics take some getting used to. :) I recommend editing it with a proportional font. It helps a lot.

Comment: Every variable in Prolog must begin with an uppercase letter *or with an underscore*. The latter is the rule you typically teach for example to Japanese users of Prolog.